# Is there any way to categorize components generated from heat.exe into features?

Tags: installation, wix

AFAIK every component should belong to some feature. So, I wonder if heat.exe has any command to categorize components it generated into features. In my case I have thousands of components. So I need some automated way to categorize the components into features. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can base your categorization on component groups. If you logically split your files into different folders, and run `heat.exe` once per each folder, you'll end up with a number of `ComponentGroup` elements. Finally, split then into features.

Probably, not exactly what you're looking for, but kind of similar. And, as @Rob suggested, XSL is always the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into `heat` to do that. The only "categorization" supported is to use XSL to transform the output. XSL can do just about anything.